# How can I use " &" with geo server ? I am getting syntax error

Tags: geoserver, error

I am unable to use special character . If I use it in my search it throws a  error. what changes do I need to do in my literals in order to get special character value from my database.

For eg : there is a value stored in my db " Ab & cd ltd "
if I try to search in my project " search building where value equals to "Ab & cd ltd"  it throws error.

The value is shown in the url in literals part but the output is not shown.

Answer (score 1):

Your client should be responsible for encoding the string you are passing to GeoServer. If this is just a simple string (i.e. a CQL filter) then you need to apply [URL Encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) (%26). If it's an XML string (i.e an OGC filter) then you need to use [an XML encoding](http://xml.silmaril.ie/specials.html) (`&amp;`)